# Pandas Highcharts - Display Chart with Flask

Tags: jquery, python, pandas, highcharts, flask

I am having an issue with displaying a Highcharts with the Pandas_Highcharts library. I have spent numerous hours playing around with JSON inputs etc and can't manage to get a graph to display at all.

Everytime I load the /graph on my browser I receive the the text "Test" but do not see any graph at all.

Using Firefox, viewing the page source leads (I have edited out various entries in the data to comply with spacing) to this:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href = "/static/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script></head>

<body>
    <p> Test </p>
    <div id="my-chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new Highcharts.Chart({"series":[{"data":[[1462838400000,2158372.6420299998],[1462752000000,1438419.8610100001],[1462665600000,667993.263726],[1462579200000,1825474.7086099999],[1462492800000,1908047.6404200001], [1304985600000,228989.8988]],"name":"Value","yAxis":0}],"yAxis":[{}],"chart":{"renderTo":"my-chart"},"xAxis":{"type":"datetime","title":{"text":"Date"}},"legend":{"enabled":true}});
    </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>     
</body>

</body>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Pandas Higcharts: https://github.com/gtnx/pandas-highcharts
It all looks so simple but why can't I make it work grr.

I do not understand why the following code ceases to work:
My relevant graph.html page:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href = "/static/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p> Test </p>
    <div id="my-chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new Highcharts.Chart({{chart|safe}});
    </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>     
</body>

</body>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

My flask python file contains the relevant @app.route('/graph')

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import pandas_highcharts.core

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/graph')
def graph_Example(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'line', chart_height = 500):
    df = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-TRVOU-BitcoinUSDExchangeTradeVolume.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates='Date')
    dataSet = pandas_highcharts.core.serialize(df, render_to='my-chart', output_type='json')
    return render_template('graph.html', chart=dataSet)
```

In general, I have various DataFrames generated using Pandas. My problem is simply being able to display them with that of HighCharts now.
My CSV files are also located here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8xdmDmZgtJbVkhCcjZkZUhaajg

In essence I want to graph each CSV file and then graph certain values against others (eg that of USD Price vs Total Bitcoins). That is my reasoning for using Pandas DataFrame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What's wrong? Show an error message or incorrect output.

Comment: Internal Server Error message. I just need some guideline help on how to correctly implement pandas_highcharts with flask. I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do so.

Comment: Run your Flask app in debug mode (`app.run(debug=True)` instead of just `app.run()`), try again, and paste the full traceback.

Comment: Okay so I've fixed a small bug but have posted the page source of what I recieve on the client side. You can see that the JSON data is getting passed successfully, but no graph is being displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the HighCharts javascript file before making use of it. Here is your file from above, but with the script tags rearranged:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href = "/static/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p> Test </p>
        <div id="my-chart"></div>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            new Highcharts.Chart({"series":[{"data":[[1462838400000,2158372.6420299998],[1462752000000,1438419.8610100001],[1462665600000,667993.263726],[1462579200000,1825474.7086099999],[1462492800000,1908047.6404200001], [1304985600000,228989.8988]],"name":"Value","yAxis":0}],"yAxis":[{}],"chart":{"renderTo":"my-chart"},"xAxis":{"type":"datetime","title":{"text":"Date"}},"legend":{"enabled":true}});
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` comes before the script tag where you create the chart.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work:

```
parse_dates = True
```